# ORA-47500: XE edition memory parameter invalid or not specified

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

Recently i tried to increase the memory_max_target in Spfile as well through cmd.But After restart the instance it shows **"ORA-47500: XE edition memory parameter invalid or not specified"**.I couldn't start the instance,but later i started by create SPfile from pfile.why this error comes after change the memory?Should i need enterprise edition??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XE is limited to 1 GB, you can not increase its memory.

[Oracle Database XE RAM Limitation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW121)

> The maximum amount of RAM that an Oracle Database XE database uses
>   cannot exceed 1 gigabyte, even if more is available.

Comment: Yes.we need enterprise edition.i think enterprise edition have limition of up to 2 GB.

Comment: EE has no 2GB limit.